# PowerShellTools.14.0.vsix fails to install with error "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products"

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I am trying to install Extention Tool PowerShellTools.14.0.vsix for Visual Studio 2015.But getting error.Please find the screenshot.
[image]

Error Log:
[image]

Visual Studio Version Installed:
[image]

Powershell version installed

[image]

Also when i checked in Extension and updates Powershell Tool for visual Studio is not showing in the list.so i manually downloaded and tried to install the Extension and failed as mentioned above

[image]

I am new to visual Studio ,so please assist me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/adamdriscoll/poshtools/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions):

> **Why can't I install in Visual Studio Express Edition?**
>
> Expression Edition only supports a very limited set of extensions. You can download [Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx). It's completely free and supports this extension.

Comment: By installing the Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition the Powershell tool got installed .